# Google Sheets Import Range if specific columns not blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet tab ("Data") with columns A:Z and need to create a tab that pulls in all rows from ("Data") if columns A:N are NOT null in any of these columns.

I've tried query importrange, query+importrange, but can't crack the code:

**Attempt #1**: =IF(isblank("Data!A1:N1"),Importrange("https:...
","Data!A1:Z100"),,))

**Attempt #2**: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https:...",
" Data!A1:Z1"), "select Col1 where Col1 is not Null", 0). <<this pulls the data in for that specific cell but I can't drag it down or across to get the other rows to populate

Help!

Answer (score 1):

join columns A:N into one column and use `TRIM`

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Data!A1:N")),,9^9))))
```

next, add this column to the range A:Z as the last column of array `{}` and `QUERY` it

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("url", "Data!A1:Z"), TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("url", "Data!A1:N")),,9^9)))}, 
 "where Col27 is not null"), 9^9, 26))
```